# What should the theme of the site be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, style

One of the [seven questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) we should answer before the end of the beta is "What should our logo and site design look like?" We need to consider several aspects of our site's design:

- What's the aesthetic of our site? (sophisticated, literary, inviting, cozy)
- What colors should be used for the navigation elements and background?
- What should our logo be?

Answer (score -6):

```
What colors should be used for the navigation elements and background?
```

1. Color of the navigation elements: `rgb(153, 1, 0)` `#990100`
2. Background: `rgb(255, 255, 255)` `#FFFFFF`

According to site [**U.S. English**](http://www.us-english.org/)